# How to find the name needed to launch app from terminal?

Tags: vmware

I read several questions similar here, but none answered my question. For example I have Vmware player installed, and I would like to launch it from terminal. `vmware` + `TAB` gives me this list:

```
vmware-authd              vmware-gksu               vmware-license-enter.sh   vmware-rpctool            vmware-user-suid-wrapper
vmware-authdlauncher      vmware-hgfsclient         vmware-modconfig          vmware-toolbox-cmd        vmware-vmblock-fuse
vmware-checkvm            vmware-hgfsmounter        vmware-mount              vmware-uninstall          vmware-xferlogs
vmwarectrl                vmware-installer          vmware-networks           vmware-unity-helper       
vmware-fuseUI             vmware-license-check.sh   vmware-ping               vmware-usbarbitrator
```

So I guess it's one of these I am supposed to launch, right? Some things I tried, but didn't give me good results: `locate vmware`, `whereis vmware`.

Is there some kind of general way (using just terminal) on how to find exact name needed to launch certain program? I know usually it's just typing program name, but as you can see in this case it does not work.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/115500/how-to-find-location-of-installed-library and http://askubuntu.com/questions/54395/location-of-file-folders-of-installed-programs

Comment: I guess you mean: how to find the *command*, needed to launch an application?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know about "Vmware player" in particular, but if it is listed under Applications in form of a Symlink > `/usr/share/applications/` you could open a preferences-dialog window on that Symlink, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and use the `Command:` name in terminal.

For instance for `Bluetooth Device Setup` the command is `bluetooth-wizard`.

[image]

Comment: It's not just using terminal though :P Anyways, yeah, apparently name I was supposed to use to launch is `vmplayer`.

Comment: Good, you figured it out! (: Basically you can find out the command as suggested, if the application is in `/usr/share/applications/` and `'~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: `/usr/share/applications/` only has: `vmware-player.desktop`, which does not really help in this case, considering name I am supposed to use is `vmplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the ps command in a bash shell to list all your running programs, if the window-app you need is opened laterly it'll be easy to find at the bottom of the list.
there you have it's process number and command running which maybe ellipsised by ps, so look in the /proc file system.