# finding path to libgsl2:i386 in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04

I needed to install gsl in Ubuntu 16.04 to run a cosmological simulation, however, I tried the command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl
```

in returned me :

```
Package libgsl0ldbl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgsl2 libgsl2:i386

E: Package 'libgsl0ldbl' has no installation candidate
```

So I typed instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl2 libgsl2:i386
```

and it seems it installed successfully, however I need to know that path where it has been installed. so I did:

```
which gsl2:i386
```

and it returned me nothing. 
Anyone have any idea how to find that path ?

Comment: What exactly do you need the path to? *I.e.*, what file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `which` command finds executable files along the PATH.  The packages you just installed sound like libraries, which I don't think are executable files (but I could be wrong).  The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115500/how-to-find-location-of-installed-library) describes how to find the location of the actual library files that you just installed.