# How to find where BLAS/LAPACK are installed?

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to build Scipy from source following these instructions: http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html#debian-ubuntu. I first installed the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc gfortran python-dev libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev cython
```

However, my Scipy unit tests do not pass, and the maintainers asked me to tell them what my BLAS and LAPACK versions are. However, I seem to find this information. How can I tell where these libraries are installed?

Using Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: The results of `apt policy libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev` in Ubuntu 20.04 are libopenblas-dev: 0.3.8 and liblapack-dev: 3.9.0.+ [How to find location of installed library](https://askubuntu.com/q/115500/)

Comment: Also please note that SciPy [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-scipy) for Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but have you tried:    whereis command?